# Issue in defining a python_path

Tags: python, linux

I have Anaconda installed on my system. Whenever I want to run a code using  OVITOS (which is a scripting interface of OVITO written in python).

I get an error:

> ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /home/leila/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/../../../libpng16.so.16)

I realized that OVITO should use only the library version from the linux system. I removed the `Python_path` from the bash, and it solved my problem. 
I was wondering how can I define a `python_path` in the bash that won't be called by OVITO?

Comment: Just a question: is it `Python_path`, `python_path` or something else? (Linux is case-sensitive)

Comment: Thanks for your question. It is PYTHONPATH.

Comment: The issue is with the site_packages:                                                                   export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/leila/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages